# How does the interrupt handler know to which thread pass the data?

Tags: operating-system, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Lets say that we are working in a unix shell and typed a command "ls". When we hit enter, an interrupt request (IRQ) is sent from a keyboard controller to a processor. When IRQ is received, the processor stops whatever it is doing, saves the execution context and runs the interrupt handler. 
I am curious how does the information about what key has been pressed is passed to the interested thread (in our case it is a thread belonging to the unix shell process)? I guess that this is the role of the interrupt handler? The code that is running when the interrupt occurs doesn't have to be the code of the unix shell, right? Cause when the thread is waiting for the IO it is blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interrupt handler most likely just saves the key code in a data structure and signals some kind of event so the desktop/window_manager/whatever_it_is can then grab the data and make it available to the currently active (console) window.

Obviously, the data can arrive at any moment and not necessarily when your program (or shell) is waiting for it inside `getchar()` or similar. And the data needs to be buffered because of that asynchronous nature of its delivery.

The ISR has very little business knowing anything about the shell or your program or how that desktop thingy deals with the rest of the keyboard data delivery.